# Why did I have gotten only null bytes argv variable from angr?

Tags: assembly, python, angr

I have made simple program to test the angr.

My python code is here.

```
import angr 
import claripy

p=angr.Project('./test2')
buf=claripy.BVS('buf', 8*10)

initial_state=p.factory.entry_state(args=["./test2", buf])

s=p.factory.simulation_manager()

s.explore(find=0x80491ab, avoid=0x80491ba)

print(s.found)

if s.found:
    sol_state=s.found[0]
    sol=sol_state.solver.eval(buf, cast_to=bytes)
    print(sol)
else:
    print("not found")
```

I expected this program print "hello"
but It printed as follows.

```
WARNING  | 2023-02-13 23:57:05,077 | angr.storage.memory_mixins.default_filler_mixin | The program is accessing memory with an unspecified value. This could indicate unwanted behavior.
WARNING  | 2023-02-13 23:57:05,077 | angr.storage.memory_mixins.default_filler_mixin | angr will cope with this by generating an unconstrained symbolic variable and continuing. You can resolve this by:
WARNING  | 2023-02-13 23:57:05,077 | angr.storage.memory_mixins.default_filler_mixin | 1) setting a value to the initial state
WARNING  | 2023-02-13 23:57:05,077 | angr.storage.memory_mixins.default_filler_mixin | 2) adding the state option ZERO_FILL_UNCONSTRAINED_{MEMORY,REGISTERS}, to make unknown regions hold null
WARNING  | 2023-02-13 23:57:05,078 | angr.storage.memory_mixins.default_filler_mixin | 3) adding the state option SYMBOL_FILL_UNCONSTRAINED_{MEMORY,REGISTERS}, to suppress these messages.
WARNING  | 2023-02-13 23:57:05,078 | angr.storage.memory_mixins.default_filler_mixin | Filling memory at 0x0 with 129 unconstrained bytes referenced from 0x819f230 (strcpy+0x0 in libc.so.6 (0x9f230))
WARNING  | 2023-02-13 23:57:05,402 | angr.storage.memory_mixins.default_filler_mixin | Filling memory at 0x7ffeff6e with 10 unconstrained bytes referenced from 0x819f230 (strcpy+0x0 in libc.so.6 (0x9f230))
[<SimState @ 0x80491ab>]
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Here is my source code test2.c and assembly code

test2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int agrc, char* argv[])
{
    char buf[10];

    strcpy(buf, argv[1]);

    if(!strcmp(buf, "hello"))
    {
        puts("Correct!");
    }
    else
    {
        puts("Incorrect");
    }
}
```

test2 assembly code

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x08049176 <+0>:     push   ebp
   0x08049177 <+1>:     mov    ebp,esp
   0x08049179 <+3>:     sub    esp,0xc
   0x0804917c <+6>:     mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
   0x0804917f <+9>:     add    eax,0x4
   0x08049182 <+12>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
   0x08049184 <+14>:    push   eax
   0x08049185 <+15>:    lea    eax,[ebp-0xa]
   0x08049188 <+18>:    push   eax
   0x08049189 <+19>:    call   0x8049050 <strcpy@plt>
   0x0804918e <+24>:    add    esp,0x8
   0x08049191 <+27>:    push   0x804a008
   0x08049196 <+32>:    lea    eax,[ebp-0xa]
   0x08049199 <+35>:    push   eax
   0x0804919a <+36>:    call   0x8049030 <strcmp@plt>
   0x0804919f <+41>:    add    esp,0x8
   0x080491a2 <+44>:    test   eax,eax
   0x080491a4 <+46>:    jne    0x80491b5 <main+63>
   0x080491a6 <+48>:    push   0x804a00e
   0x080491ab <+53>:    call   0x8049060 <puts@plt>
   0x080491b0 <+58>:    add    esp,0x4
   0x080491b3 <+61>:    jmp    0x80491c2 <main+76>
   0x080491b5 <+63>:    push   0x804a017
   0x080491ba <+68>:    call   0x8049060 <puts@plt>
   0x080491bf <+73>:    add    esp,0x4
   0x080491c2 <+76>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x080491c7 <+81>:    leave
   0x080491c8 <+82>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
```

Why is this happening?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not use the `initial_state` you create with constraints for `buf` arg.
From the doc

> If nothing is passed in, the SimulationManager is seeded with a state initialized for the program entry point, i.e. entry_state().
> If a SimState is passed in, the SimulationManager is seeded with that state.

```
s = p.factory.simulation_manager(initial_state)
```

would just do it

```
[<SimState @ 0x4007a3>]
b'hello\x00\x08\x80\x00\x00'
```